# WPF ComboBox update source

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a **ComboBox** with country codes and phone numbers (+43.., ..)
The **ItemsSource** is a list of Country objects with many properties (Code is one of them.)
The **DataContext** in which the ComboBox is located is an object with the PhoneNumber property.

When user selects a country in the list, I want to update the source PhoneNumber Property(which is a string) with the '+43' value from the Country object.
The list appears, but the source is never updated. How to do that?
When I replace it with this TextBox, everything works fine:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CountryCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static Member=data:Country.AllCountries}" SelectedValuePath="Country.Value.Code" SelectedValue="??" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the solution by myself:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static Member=data:Country.AllCountries}" SelectedValuePath="PhonePrefix" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CountryCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

Comment: I had a different question, but it turned out that you answer helped me anyway, since in my case the blocking was not specifying "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"...